# How do I abstract similar validations/relations to parent class in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby, validation, refactoring, parent, database-relations

I have these VERY similar classes:

```
class DeliveryDocument < CommercialDocument
  # Relations
  belongs_to :biller, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :customer_center, :class_name => 'Center'
  has_many :delivery_document_lines, :dependent => :destroy
  alias_attribute :lines, :delivery_document_lines
  # Some configuration
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_document_lines
  acts_as_freezable :only_dependencies => true,
    :has_many => [:delivery_document_lines],
    :belongs_to => [:biller, :customer, :customer_center]
  acts_as_clonable :has_many => [:delivery_document_lines]
  validates_each :lines do |record, attr, value|
    # ...
  end
end
```

And:

```
class InvoiceDocument < CommercialDocument
  self.
  # Relations
  belongs_to :biller, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :customer_center, :class_name => 'Center'
  has_many :invoice_document_lines, :dependent => :destroy
  alias_attribute :lines, :invoice_document_lines
  # Some configuration
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_document_lines
  acts_as_freezable :only_dependencies => true,
    :has_many => [:invoice_document_lines],
    :belongs_to => [:biller, :customer, :customer_center]
  acts_as_clonable :has_many => [:invoice_document_lines]
  # Validations
  validates_each :lines do |record, attr, value|
    # ...
  end
end
```

I also have some methods I didn't paste that could be extracted to the parent. I only need to know the class name in the parent. When I do this:

```
class CommercialDocument < Document  # document inherits from AR::Base
  # ...
  has_many :"#{self.to_s.underscore}_lines", :dependent => :destroy
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :"#{self.to_s.underscore}_lines"
  # ...
end
```

it doesn't work, because `self.to_s` is `CommercialDocument`.

How would you refactor this behavior in parent class? 
I could put things in a module and import it, but then the whole hierarchy of documents becomes almost useless.
I already have the documents' hierarchy, so if I can, I want to use it if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Class.inherited](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html#M000177)

Comment: I think i cant use Class.inherited. It is called after all then childs code has been completely evaluated. There are some methods that i cant refactorize but they need that relations to work.

Comment: not sure I follow why it wouldn't work. Did you try something like `subclass.send :has_many, :"#{subclass.to_s.underscore}_lines"` in your inherited method?